# Variable "form" does not exist, when creation $form = $this->createForm(

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have the problem, that symfony said, that he can't find the variable "form":

My controller is:

```
(...)
        $login = array();

        $form = $this->createForm(new LoginType(), $login, array('action' => $this->generateUrl('login_check')));
        return $this->render('AppBundle:Authentication:login.html.twig',
            array(
                'error'=> $error,
                'form' => $form->createView())
            );
    }
```

for more clarification and to the answer:
changed:

```
render('AppBundle:Authentication:login.html.twig',
and the template:
```

into

```
render('AppBundle:Security:login.html.twig',
```

my template:
Folder: Security/login.html.twig

```
{% extends 'AppBundle:Security:layout.html.twig' %}

{% block main_content %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

What did I wrong, that symfony can't find "form"?

My error message is:

```
Variable "form" does not exist in AppBundle:Security:login.html.twig
at line 4
```

Comment: You are using the wrong template:
`AppBundle:Security:login.html.twig` but in the controller is setted the `AppBundle:Authentication:login.html.twig` maybe there is some problems with the inheritance configurations

Comment: thank you! I didn't see it, but I still have: `Variable "form" does not exist in AppBundle:Security:login.html.twig at line 4`

Comment: Than change the controller too

Comment: Thank your really much for your help! I found the error: I forgot * @Template("AppBundle:Security:login.html.twig")

Comment: `@Template()` is not necessary if you use the `render()` function.